# Sorting for array not working properly with Internet Explorer 10 and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I need to sort array . But i am not getting desired result on internet explorer.

```
var s = [1,2,3,4,2,1,2,8,0,5];
var y = _.sortBy(s,function(item1, item2) { return (item1 < item2); });

o/p: [object Array][1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 2, 1, 2, 0, 5]
```

Also tried :

```
var y = s.sort(function(item1, item2) { return (item1 < item2); });
o/p object Array][1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 8, 0, 5]
```

with InternetExplorer 10 , i am not getting sorted array. any idea .

```
var y = s.sort(function(item1, item2) { return (item1 < item2); });
```

working fine on chrome and mozilla? but not

```
var y = _.sortBy(s,function(item1, item2) { return (item1 < item2); });
```

This is working with just chrome.

Same sorting concept i am using to sort json array , eg.

```
var employees = [
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "age": 23}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "age": 12}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones", "age": 5},
    {"firstName":"John1", "lastName":"Doe1", "age": 3},
    {"firstName":"John2", "lastName":"Doe2", "age": 13},  
];

var y = employee.sort(function(item1, item2) { 
  var age1 = item1.age;
  var age2 = item2.age;

  return (age1< age2); });
}
```

Not getting desired result, as mentioned above

Comment: why do you even need a sort callback? `s.sort()` should work fine . Also are any errors thrown

Comment: Actually i want to sort my json array. This is sample array i took as an example

Comment: Don't over simplify examples. You stated that what was shown doesn't work. We can't read minds nor reproduce your problem

Comment: but this should work, right?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with the snippets in the question:

1. The function that you pass to the Javascript array [**sort**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function is expected to return a number and not a boolean. If item1 comes before item2 then return a negative number, if item1 comes after item2 return a positive number and if item1 and item2 should remain where they are in the array then return 0. So in your example you could change the comparison in the function from `return item1 < item2` to `return item1 - item2`.
2. The function passed to Underscore's [**sortBy**](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) in your example should take a single parameter. The value of the parameter will be each item in the array being sorted. The function is expected to return a value which will be used to rank the item in the array. Underscore can also take the name of a property whose value is used for the sort.

To sort employees by age you could do any of the the following:

```
var sorted = _.sortBy(employees, 'age');

var sorted = _.sortBy(employees, function(e){
    return e.age;
});

var sorted = employees.sort( function(e1,e2){
    return e1.age - e2.age;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed this approach and got correct response on all 3 browsers.:

```
var y = s.sort(function(count1, count2) {

if (count1 < count2) {
          return 1;
        } else if (count1 > count2) {
          return -1;
        }
return 0;
});
```